# How to permanently disable EEE (Energy Efficient Ethernet) on Ethernet card?

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet, power-management

I am looking for a kernel parameter that I could use in the GRUB config to **disable EEE** (Energy Efficient Ethernet, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet)) permanently on my LAN (wired Ethernet) card of my newish laptop:

Basic info:

OS: [Linux Mint 21.1 "Vera" Cinnamon](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=302)

```
# ethtool -i enp59s0 
driver: r8169
version: 5.15.0-56-generic
firmware-version: rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:3b:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

---

What works (not persistent upon reboots, and sleeps & wakeups):

```
# ethtool --set-eee enp59s0 eee off
```

However, I would rather not have to set up a @reboot CRON for this.

What I've tried on a running machine, as suggested [here](https://community.toradex.com/t/how-to-disable-energy-efficient-ethernet/6602/2), and [here](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=173065), and other places:

```
# sysctl -w igb.EEE=0
# sysctl -w e1000e.EEE=0
# sysctl -w r8169.EEE=0
```

all of which ended up with an error message:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/[PARAM]/EEE: No such file or directory
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No such kernel parameter exists.

However, there are other ways to achieve your goal than an `@reboot` cron job.

If you're using NetworkManager, you could create a pre-up dispatcher script (e.g. `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/disable-eee`) to make the configuration change as the network interface is activated:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#
# Disable EEE on enp59s0

if [ "$1" = "enp59s0" ]; then
        /sbin/ethtool --set-eee $1 eee off \
            || /bin/logger "Error $? trying to disable EEE on $1"
fi

exit 0
```

Be sure to mark the script executable.

---

Alternatively, you could create `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-eee` to change the setting as the kernel module is loaded:

```bash
install r8169 /sbin/modprobe -i r8169 && sleep 1 && /sbin/ethtool --set-eee enp59s0 eee off
```

(If the `r8169` kernel module is loaded in initramfs boot phase, you might have to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` before this can take effect on next boot.)

---

Or you could create your own `systemd` service unit to run the ethtool command (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/disable-eee.service`):

```bash
[Unit]
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool --set-eee enp59s0 eee off

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**Important Note**:

Depending on your OS config, `ethtool` may be placed someplace else like `/usr/sbin/ethtool` in Vlastimil's case. If you are unsure, you may run `which ethtool` or `command -v ethtool`. The same goes for the `logger` program.